# Excel missing data after import

Tags: excel, mysql-workbench

I have exported a database table from my school into a CSV file.

Now I wanted to upload this CSV file into my SQL workbench. When I import it, it makes nor errors, but there a missing a lot of rows.

My files has got almost 40 k rows, after my import in SQL workbench i have only 26k.

I removed the limit to show all rows, but changed nothing.

What did I wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the original file has 40k rows?

Comment: Yes im sure, over 10 k missing

Comment: Was it properly delimited a having no blank lines.

Comment: Someone any idea?